# How to turn a constraint list in pyomo into a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyomo

I am developing a production model and a very long list of constraints (ca. 600). How can I export the list to an excel file for analysis?

so far i am using model.cons.pprint() to generate a visualisation of the constraints at runtime. However its very cumbersome to review 100s of lines in a terminal window.

This is the current solution that produces an output in the terminal window at runtime.

```py
# define constraints
model.cons = pyomo.ConstraintList()
#
# ....
#
model.cons.pprint()
#
```

this produces
Size=577, Index=cons_index, Active=True,  Key : Lower  : Body                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           : Upper    : Active
and then 577 lines of constraints. which is fine to get started.

i have tried the following to generate a dataframe,

```py
df_cons = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(model.cons.extract_values(), orient='index', columns=[str(model.cons)])
print(df_cons)
print("--------------")
```

However this did not work.

I am looking for a command to export the constraint list to a dataframe or write directly to an excel file.

Comment: Are you trying to save the string representations of the constraint expressions or the value of the constraint expressions? It may be easier to work with your model if you declare multiple indexed constraints instead of one long ConstraintList, especially if different sets of your constraints have distinct interpretations.

Comment: Yes, i would like to see the string expression of the constraint list. I was hoping there was a way to reproduce what pprint does at runtime into a dump that i could then store and analyse further if needed.

Comment: You could always use pprint to write to a file: `m.pprint(filename='mymodel.txt')`

Comment: Thanks Bethany for getting back. I have typed the following: model.cons.pprint(filename='mymodel.txt') and got the following error   File "ext_mod_v0k.py", line 220, in <module>
    model.cons.pprint(filename='mymodel.txt')
TypeError: pprint() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filename' any idea how to resolve? thanks again for looking into this.

Comment: ok, solved with this construct 
stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout 
sys.stdout = open("C:\\Apps\cons_dump.txt", "w")
model.cons.pprint()
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout=stdoutOrigin

Comment: this uses pprint, but instead of filling up the screen for a few minute with long sets of data it directs the screen output to a txt file. this can then be imported into excel, and voila, the complete constraint expression becomes visible. which is handy if you have 100000 or so constraints and you need to find an issue.